# Clarification on Feed Me > Feed URL

Tags: plugin-feedme

The [Feed Me documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/creating-your-feed.html) says

> "Provide the URL for your feed. This can be an absolute URL, relative (to the web root) and make use of any aliases"

That's pretty confusing language. I thought I could create a folder in public called "feeds" that would contain my .csv. For example, /public/feeds/feed.csv. So I entered feeds/feed.csv in the Feed URL field. That didn't work. I was confused because "relative (to the web root)" doesn't really mean a relative path.

Is it true that the Feed URL needs to be an absolute URL in the form of http(s)://domain.tld/feed/feed.csv? I understand that aliases can be used and you wouldn't necessarily need to enter the domain in this field, but in general is this the required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i placed  a test file named test.json in web folder of Craft CMS and put test.json in feed URL and it doesn't work -so it is not relative to web root as default-.

but when it says absolute format i believe it is  `/var/www/html/craft/web/test.json` -in local ubuntu, in your case maybe `{maybe top folders}/public/feeds/feed.csv`- or as path alias format: `@webroot/test.json` which both of them works for me.

as you mentioned URL format `http(s)://domain.tld/test.json` or `@web/test.json` works too.

[docs for path alias](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an external feed as your source - yes, you are right, it needs to be an absolute URL.

However, you can use aliases defined by Craft CMS and Yii2 to access a directory within the installation. [(please refer to the aliases here)](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases)

For example, if your feed is inside the **storage/feeds/import.xml**, you can refer to it in the Feed configuration as:

```
@storage/feeds/import.xml
```

Comment: '@storage' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/storage',

Unable to reach @storage/feeds/docs.json. Message: Unable to parse data.