# Feed me plugin, cURL error 60

Tags: error, import

This is my first time using the Feed Me import plugin (craft 3.5.15.1). I'm pointing the feed URL to a file in the  public root, e.g. http://dev.mydomain.com/import.csv. When executing the import, I get this error:

> Unable to reach http://dev.mydomain.com/import.csv. Message: cURL
> error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate

I don't understand why. The site is a subdomain of a site that uses an SSL, but the dev subdomain does not and I've not had any other issues with craft or the browser expecting an SSL.

Any ideas why or more information I can provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try adding the following to your `feed-me.php` config file:

```php
<?php

return [
    '*' => [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'verify' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

c.f. https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/479

As noted [here](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify), this is generally not a very secure practice but should be fine if you're just wanting to import a local file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35412/clarification-on-feed-me-feed-url) helped me the the ensuing 404 error.